# Convert Python request with image to cURL

Tags: java, python, file, curl, python-requests

I found this example of a API request. Unfortunately I didn't find any other example how to upload an image to the API.
As I'm not familiar with Python I'm trying to understand how to do the same in a cURL command.

```
import requests

auth_headers = {
    'app_id': 'your_app_id',
    'app_key': 'your_app_key'
}

url = 'https://XXXXXXX'
files = {
    'source': open('media/test.jpg')
}
data = {
    'timeout': 60
}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=auth_headers)
```

I tried to convert it by trying out a cURL to python converter, but I don't know how to build it with the files.

In the end I want to do the request in JAVA, but I think if I would know the request in cURL I can figure it out.

Hope anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(
    -H 'app_id: your_app_id'
    -H 'app_key: your_app_key'
    -F 'source=@/path/to/file'
    -F 'timeout=60'
    'http://httpbin.org/post'
)
curl "${args[@]}"
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
curl -H 'app_id: your_app_id' -H 'app_key: your_app_key' -F 'source=@/path/to/file' -F 'timeout=60' 'http://httpbin.org/post'
```

Use [`-H`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) to specify header fields (repeat for every field) and [`-F`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) to specify form fields - either as `key=value` pairs, or `filename=@path` pairs. When `-F` is used, `POST` method is the default, and `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` (but that too can be overridden).

Comment: Perfect, thank you a lot. Also thanks for the multipart/form-data hint